# "require" is not defined error- javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I get this error in the browser when I run my .html file

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

My File_system.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>window.requestFileSystem problem</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="server.js"></script>
<script>
function onInitFs(fs) {
console.log(fs);   
console.log(fs.getDirectory());
}

function errorHandler(e) {
var msg = '';
console.log(e);

switch (e.code) {
case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
  msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
  break;
case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
  msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
  break;
case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
  msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
  break;
case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
  msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
  break;
case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
  msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
  break;
default:
  msg = 'Unknown Error';
  break;
};

console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024,onInitFs,errorHandler);

</script> 
</head> 
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

And my server.js file is:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('File_system.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.end(index);
}).listen(8080);
```

What is wrong with this? Please help

I should be able to retrieve all the fs methods in the console and create a directory with tat. But I am stuck in this. 
Or is there any way to directly run in browser?

Comment: Your server.js is a nodejs file, not for browser.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as the correct answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Rereading your original post, it's possible that you *are* in fact running this Node.js script in a Node environment, trying to use `fs` to load your .html file. If that's the case, you are calling your Node server.js script *within* your .html file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="server.js"></script>
```

Simply remove this line, and you should no longer receive the error you're seeing.

---

As previously stated, you're attempting to implement [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) code in your client-side script. In theory this [can be done](https://github.com/jed/browserver-client), but isn't recommended, and Node.js simply isn't designed for this purpose (it's a server!)

You should be using [`XHR/ajax`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to make http requests from your client to a server (not `fs`), and then handle those things on the back end. This can be done easily with a conventional web stack like Apache and php, or if you really want to use `fs`, run an API off of Node.js and connect your client to it using [`XHR/ajax`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest), or implement an MVC stack like [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org).

Comment: Ok I got what its all about. But with `fs` I want to create directory. So if I cannot get `fs` from server.js. How to use in .html to do things like..for eg: `onInitFs(fs) `

Comment: Not sure at all what you're asking? Sounds like an entirely new question to me ;)

Comment: Its easy....See...I am using server.js to create fs, so I want to use this fs to create a directory and store something and use that to create webpage(setting up a server to store/retrieve files). So if I dont get to access fs in my html, how do I use it. I am sure there is some method to do this.

Comment: You simply can't do that. You need to build a back-end API service to handle it.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any demo example out there? I am not finding a single piece of code to do that. I searched and still searching for it.

Comment: If you're up for using jQuery, they make it really easy with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/); If not, you can do it natively in javascript. For the server, see the Sails.js link I put in the answer, or you can use a php framework like CodeIgniter or Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use your node.js script in browser. Only run it with node.js.

Comment: Unless you use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) (a note as reference*)

Answer (score 2):

`server.js` should run in the server side (which has nodejs be installed).

Comment: Then how do I fetch fs and create directory and stuff in my html5?

Comment: You don't. File system access in the browser is for the most part disallowed for security reasons.