# How do I access variables/functions in bundle.js

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

hello how do you access variables in bundle.js?

I am trying to make a client side javascript and play around with variables and functions but am having trouble calling them in index.html, chrome-console.

I use browserify to bundle my script.js into bundle.js (which helps me with 'require' which the browser does not recognize), however when I try to access variables or functions defined in the script.js, now bundle.js I get e.g. Uncaught ReferenceError: xx is not defined

Any help? Or am I not allowed to use node packages on client side html/scripts?

edit: did a bit of googling and came upon this guy who says I should use XHR / AJAX ["require" is not defined error- javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605118/require-is-not-defined-error-javascript)

edit2: window.xx = xx seems to be a temporary solution

Comment: Have you imported your script using a script tag in your html?  for example: `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: yup I have imported my script!

Comment: I think [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581803/how-to-export-global-variable-from-browserify-babelify-to-be-used-in-project-wit) but the question is rather unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, because I have not used Browserify (I've used other bundling/processing tools), but to my understanding, Browserify bundles up all the code from the original source file into a `bundle.js` file. Within that `bundle.js` is a scope that is not accessible from the outside (unless specifically exported perhaps, but that's another story).

So for example:

```js
// source.js
var test = require('./some-file-with-an-empty-object.js');
```

```js
// Pseudo code example of bundle.js
;(function(){
   var test = {};
})();
```

Because of this [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), the scope `var test` is limitted and not accessible to external scripts or `window`.

So in short, do what you need to do within your source file, not outside of it.